# Problems with adding query parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Code:

```
com.CommandText = "select username, pass from Employees where lastName like '@Last' and firstName like '@First'";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", lastName); // lastName is a method argument

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@First";
param.Value = firstName;
com.Parameters.Add(param);
```

No matter what I do, the parameters are not inserted. What gives?

Comment: What happens, do you get an exception?  If so, what is the exception?

Comment: As I said, the parameters are not inserted; the string has literal @Last and @First.

Comment: Are you using Sql profiler to see the command sent to the server?  How are you determining that "the string has literal @Last and @First"?  What do you mean by this?

Comment: I print the CommandText in a textbox just before I execute it. Also this prompted me to use a debugger, which confirms this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not put single quotes around your parameters, these are implied anyway.

Also, try using SqlCommand.CreateParameter as well:

```
com.CommandText = "select username, pass from Employees where lastName like @Last and firstName like @First";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", lastName); // lastName is a method argument

SqlParameter param = com.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@First";
param.Value = firstName;
com.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change the '@Last' to @Last, same thing for First...

Comment: myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = firstName